# can't publish facebook single achievements

Tags: php, facebook, graph

I am using https://graph.facebook.com/myuid/achievements/POST/?achievement=achievement_url&access_token=app_access_token.
But this url is returning empty data array.I have publish_action permission.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a GET request here, but this needs to be a POST to

```
/v2.1/me/achievements
```

as stated at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/achievements/#publish with

```
achievement={url-of-achievement-type}
```

as POST body. Replace `{url-of-achievement-type}` with the actual URL of your achievement.

Comment: how can I send post request here?